# How to make chai test passing?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, react-redux, chai

I have written my first unit test for a reactjs app:

```
 it('should display  props.text', () => {
        const props = {
           data: {
              completed: false,
              id: 1,
              text: 'hey boer'
           }
        };

        const wrapper = mount(<SubComponent {...props} />);
        const part = wrapper.find('.mystuff');

        //try to see whether the mockdata is present
        expect(part).to.contain('hey boer');
 });
```

This is my component:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export class SubComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
       console.log('cons servicedetails props', props);
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="mystuff">this is the subcomponent. {this.props.myprops.data.text}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default SubComponent;
```

When I run the test I get this error:

```
 SubComponent should display  props.text:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

How can I check whether my props(mock)data are actually injected into the SubComponent?My program runs without errors but the unit test throws errors? see also [here](https://github.com/dimitri-a/samplecode_so)

Answer (score 3):

There is no assertion as `text` on chai api.

You should do something like-

> expect('foobar').to.contain('foo');

Comment: problem is on your `render` function. Edit `{this.props.myprops.data.text}` to `{this.props.data.text}`